# Sliding transition not working

Tags: android

I have some code that seems correct to me but seems to have a very jumpy transition and I was wondering whether any one could solve the problem.

right to left anim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

     <translate
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromXDelta="-100%"
         android:fromYDelta="0%"
         android:toXDelta="0%"
         android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

left to right anim

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromXDelta="0%"
         android:fromYDelta="0%"
         android:toXDelta="100%"
         android:toYDelta="0%" />
    </set>
```

and I use the transition in an onclick with an Intent (i figure this may be the problem but seems to work fine left to right)

code for onclick

```
Reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);

            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_exit, R.anim.left_to_right_exit);
```

thanks in advance for any help on the issue.

Comment: what is the problem occure in this ??

Comment: The main activity will slide out left and then 'glitch' back in front then slide out right

Comment: remove your `anim` file and add my `file` and use my Transition as I write.

Answer (score 0):

Create `slide_in_right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Create `fade_back.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:pivotX="50.0%"
        android:pivotY="50.0%"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.9"/>
    <alpha android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.7"/>
</set>
```

and finally add this

`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.fade_back);`

## UpDate :

If you want below transition like `Image`. Then use this.

[image]

**code for open_translate.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="500"
               android:fromXDelta="100%"      
               android:toXDelta="0"/>
    <alpha android:duration="500"
           android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
           android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

**code for close_scale.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
     <translate android:duration="500"
                android:fromXDelta="0"
                android:toXDelta="-100%p"/>
<alpha android:duration="500"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: This works fine but i want the current activity to fade to the left.

Comment: for some reason the two activities just move into each other.